# How can I get Express JS to keep local variables upon server restarts?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using an Express server in NodeJS v14.15.1 to handle HTTP GET and POST requests. The server performs some cryptographic operations and obtains a key which must be used for subsequent requests. The obtained key is set as a global variable within my `index.js` file (where my `express()` app resides). However, the server restarts automatically (I am using *nodemon*) upon handling each HTTP request, and in doing so it erases the key global variable. So the next request which relies on reading the global key variable is unable to succeed. **NB:** The key **cannot** be stored on-disk or on the client-side due to security reasons. Also, this is for a university assignment, not a real production environment.

**How can I keep the global variable upon server restart?**

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the nodejs/Express environment automatically survives from one restart to the next.  So, if you have specific data that you want to always be available after a restart, then you would typically save it to disk (often in a JSON file) every time it changes and then every time your server starts, it can read that state from the previous JSON file and initialize your variables from that data.

> However, the server restarts automatically (I am using nodemon) upon handling each HTTP request

This should not happen, so your first thing to solve it to stop the server from restarting.  Your server should run for days or weeks and be able to field millions of http requests without restarting.  Is the server crashing and restarting or is nodemon seeing something change and automatically killing/restarting your server?

Nodemon is sometimes used in a "developer" mode such that it automatically restarts your server anytime files in a specific directory are changed.  This can facilitate faster development cycles if you are editing your source files.  But, this should NOT be happening except when you edit your server source files and only when you are using nodemon in a "debug" or "development" mode.  If this is why nodemon is restarting your server, then you probably need to tweak the configuration so it isn't detecting file changes that are part of your normal server operation and thus doesn't restart just because your server does something normal.

> The key cannot be stored on-disk

Well, there's no simple way to get data to survive a server restart without storing the data somewhere.  NOTHING from your Express process survives a restart so you can't only keep it in the Express process if you want to have access to it again after a restart.  So, it appears to me that you've put yourself in a box.

Your options are to either stop the server from restarting in the first place or find a secure place to store the key.

Comment: Thanks for the well-explained and informative answer. Nodemon is restarting the server each time I hit CTRL+S in my text editor, and it is also resarting each time any HTTP request is successfully handled by the express server. If I can stop this from happening, then I think my global variable will not get deleted. Will let you know how it turns out.

Comment: @QuentinJames - What are your http requests doing?  Are they writing to a database or to a file?  That's my guess and nodemon thinks you've edited your source so it is restarting.  You can either turn that feature off in nodemon or configure it to ignore the specific file that is being modified or move that file to another directory where nodemon is not monitoring.

Comment: Yep that's it, my express server is writing to a file on-disk. That must be triggering nodemon to restart the server, making me think that it's the requests which are somehow causing the restart. Will disable nodemon tomorrow and hopefully solve this. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: @QuentinJames - That would be it.  FYI, if you still want to use nodemon for other reasons, you can use a [config file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon#user-content-config-files) or a specific section in your `package.json` file with the `ignore` option in it that lets you tell it to ignore certain files or directories when looking for changes.